# What is the correct notation for parametric distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose r.v. $X$ has discrete uniform $(1,N)$ distribution, i.e. the r.v. takes integer value from 1 to $N$ with the same probabilty. In the Statsitical Inference by Casella, it denotes the distribution as $$P(X=x\mid N)=\frac{1}{N}.$$
However, I have seem many other books and sources denote parametric distribution as $$P(X=x; N)=\frac{1}{N}.$$ My question is which one is more suitable? My main concern for the first notation is that it mathces the notation of the conditional probability. I think different $N$ is best thought of as different proability space, so we should not use the first notation since it means conditional probability. Also, I think it is still possible to construct a single probability space with multiple $N$ attributes to probability space, right?

Comment: The first notation is common in Bayesian settings, where the parameter has a prior distribution.

Comment: If the parameter is a random variable, then use the first, if an unknown constant, then use the latter.

Comment: Both of these comments are sensible, but in my experience, authors of texts tend to use their favorite notations regardless of context.Both versions are sufficiently often used, that it would be difficult to say one is correct and the other is wrong.